# I am getting error in cookie when refresh browser

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am using jquery.cookie.js library to create cookies. But some time when cookie is created and I reload the page I get this error:

> 400 Bad request

Your browser sent an invalid request.

Please see the attached screenshot. cookie is created correctly 
[image]

```
$.cookie( 'cookiename', datavar, { expires: 7 ,  path: '/'});
```

Can any body please help

Comment: What is in `datavar`? That's kind if pertinent...

Comment: Use a tool such as fiddler to view the request headers